# How to migrate a value into a field attached to a taxonomy_term (from CSV using YML)

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm trying to migrate a CSV file of taxonomies (cities) into Drupal 8. The CSV has a code and the city name, for example:

```
City_Code,"Name"
1234,"CITY A"
5678,"CITY B"
```

I have the following as my current migration, which is working, and importing the city names. My problem is I also added a field with the machine name `field_legacy_id` to my term (Drupal 8), which I would like to populate with the OLD `City_Code` for reference later.

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: cities
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: null
label: 'My Import'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: /path/to/data.csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - City_Code
  column_names:
    0:
      City_Cd: City_Code
    1:
      Name: Name
process:
  vid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: city
  name: Name
  field_leagcy_id: City_Code
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:taxonomy_term'
migration_dependencies: null
```

The `field_legacy_id` seems to be ignored and I can't figure out how to get the migration to populate the field value. Thanks.

Edit: This is the field attached to the `taxonomy.vocabulary.city`:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_legacy_id
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.city
id: taxonomy_term.city.field_legacy_id
field_name: field_legacy_id
entity_type: taxonomy_term
bundle: city
label: legacy_id
description: ''
required: false
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  min: null
  max: null
  prefix: ''
  suffix: ''
field_type: integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the field name is misspelled?

```
  field_leagcy_id: City_Code
```